# Dynamic url parameter using iis rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a url like this:
http://localhost:8085/product/1/something

Note: something is optional

I've expected to go to http://localhost:8085/product/1.html, When I entered above url .

Here is my attempt :

```
    <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="\/product\/(\d+)\/.*" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="product/{R:1}.html" />
    </rule>
```

But it cause an error:

```
HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
The expression "product/{R:1} .html" cannot be expanded.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please go back and follow the very basic tutorial to learn how to write URL rewrite rules, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module#viewing-the-rewrite-rule-in-configuration-file

Comment: The above rule was based on this tutorial , but it can't work for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="DifferentFolder" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="product/([0-9]+)/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="product/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```